# Borders looking blurry in chrome

Tags: css

i am using 1 px solid border in input type text's and emails and passwords. but the thickness of the borders are not perfect in every side of the input box border left and right is fine but top and bottom is looking little hazy. some places the borders are looking correct but in some places it looks blurry. Please find the attached image.

CSS :

```
.input-control{
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #D8DAE6;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 27px 20px 16px 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #696969;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please include your code in the question.

Comment: @John Montgomery I have included my code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

It might because of the low-resolution screen. I have the same issue since my screen is 1366x768. When you have a low-resolution screen, the pixels breakout when there is a minute detail like 1px width.

For better understanding, you can resize your browser window, it will show the variable width on resizing.

Comment: My resolution is 1920*1080. If i zoom 5 times then it looks OK though.

Comment: Even if you have a relatively good resolution you will still get pixel breakup. It is unavoidable in web development.

Comment: And the fact that it looks fine on zoom proves that.